# Problemas con Mysql

Tags: mysql, ssh

Tengo una base de datos mysql almacenada en un servidor, me conecto remotamente por ssh y accedo desde ahí a las bases de datos, pero al momento de salir de la sesión por ssh, mis demás compañeros que también se conectan a la base de datos del servidor ya no pueden acceder a ella, es decir si cierro la sesión ssh se cae automáticamente mysql. Alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que podría estar pasando.

Comment: ¿Qué comando usas para cerrar sesión?

Comment: creo que ya lo resolvi, porque cerraba la sesion ssh dandole a la x del recuadro, ahora utilizo el comando exit para salir de la sesion y me sigue permitiendo entrar a la base de datos. Gracias de igual forma.

Comment: Podrías añadir el log de MySQL y del SSH para que podamos saber exactamente que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando el comando `pkill`? recuerda que puedes cerrar tu sesión unicamente, por ejemplo

```
pkill -9 -t pts/3
```

Lo obtienes primero con el comando `who` que en este ejemplo debe ser `pts/3`.

Comment: pero lo que quiero es que al desconectarme de ssh no se caiga mysql, que puedan seguir teniendo acceso a la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

lo que puede estar pasando es que inicias el servidor `mysqld` bajo tu sesión personal de SSH as´ que cuando cierras el process ssh en tu PC/laptop cliente la session remota termina la ejecución de todos los procesos iniciados durante la sesión. Lo que debes hacer es configurar MySQL para que inicie como daemon bajo su propio usuario es decir; el admin (root) del servidor debe crear un usuario nuevo y dentro de ese usuario configurar el servicio mysql, dependiendo del servidor Sistema Operativo los pasos para configurar el servicio serán diferentes.

Comment: La verdd son nueva en esto de los servidores, me podrias decir como hacer el cambio de daemon, estoy bajo un sistema debian jessie y como conexion remota un windows 10, otra duda eso lo tengo que hacer desde la maquina del servidor o se puede crear remotamente?, te agradeceria que me puedas ayudar con los comandos. Muchas gracias.